# Python imaplib hiding plaintext password

Tags: python, security, passwords, imaplib

This is the Python snippet I'm using to connect to the server.

```
m= imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
m.login('user@gmail.com', 'password')
```

Is there an easy/painless way to avoid having the password shown as plaintext in the script?  I think this is a valid security concern?

Comment: You could try to encrypt or obfuscate the password, but since your script would at some point decrypt/deobfuscate the password, it wouldn't stop anyone. If you don't want your password to be derivable from your script, you can't put your password into your script.

Comment: IMAP is inherently insecure, and you will leak passwords over the wire even if you obfuscate.

Comment: Is this a personal script or something you want to distribute? If personal, what OS are you using?